# Determining $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}[-n,3^{-n}]$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I have the problem to determine what $$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}[-n,3^{-n}]$$ is. I thought the solution was $[-1,0)$ however it turned out to be $[-1,0]$. Why is this so when $3^{-n}$ will never reach $0$?

Comment: If every interval $[-n,3^{-n}]$ contains 0, why would the intersection exclude it?

Comment: Oh of course, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that $3^{-n} = \frac 1{3^n}> 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. So *every* interval necessarily contains $0$ since $-n\lt 0 \lt 3^{-n}$, for all $n \in \mathbb N$.